# Return large subgraphs from a list of Ids in Cypher (Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a question regarding the use of the Neo4j client for Java. I have a graph with about 120.000.000 nodes and 1.000.000.000 edges. From this graph, I want to extract subgraphs (average size about 500 nodes). For this purpose, I have created an index on the Id fields of the nodes.
The queries look like this

```
MATCH (a:XXX:YYYY) 
WHERE a.uid IN [9999, 5555, 7777, 99999, ...] 
RETURN a AS blablubb
```

At the moment I am looking for the edges with a second query that looks like this

```
MATCH (a::XXX:YYYY)-[r:ZZZZ]-(b::XXX:YYYY)
WHERE a.uid IN [9999, 5555, 7777, 99999, ...]
AND b.uid IN [9999, 5555, 7777, 99999, ...]
```

This is very very slow especially when the subgraphs get bigger.
My question now is how can I connect the two queries to get both the edges and the nodes of the subgraph at once. I know that there is a faster solution because the Neo4j browser gives me a
a visualization for

```
MATCH (a:XXX:YYYY) 
WHERE a.uid IN [9999, 5555, 7777, 99999, ...] 
RETURN a AS blablubb
```

which contains all edges.

thank you very much for your help

Comment: As far as I know, Neo4j browser makes a second request in order to fetch the edges. Does anybody know how this request looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I have divided the query into two different queries. The first one fetched the nodes

```
MATCH (a:XXX:YYYY) 
WHERE a.uid IN [9999, 5555, 7777, 99999, ...] 
RETURN a AS node
```

and the second

```
MATCH (n:Uid)
WHERE n.uid IN [9999, 5555, 7777, 99999, ...]
WITH collect(n) AS nds
UNWIND nds AS n1
MATCH (n1)-[r]-(n2)
WHERE n2 IN nds
RETURN r AS relation
```

the edges. For some reason, it gets very slow when I try to combine the two and get the list of edges and the list of nodes. The overall solution is not very satisfying but at least I was able to archive an acceptable performance.

Comment: You should make `MATCH (n1)-[r]-(n2)` as a directed query like `MATCH (n1)-[r]->(n2)` so your query doesn't have to make the same matches in reverse. It will cut your result set in half.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler and more efficient version of your own answer:

```
WITH [9999, 5555, 7777, 99999, ...] AS wanted
MATCH (n:Uid)-[r]->(n2)
WHERE n.uid IN wanted AND n2 IN wanted
RETURN r AS relation
```

If you pass in `wanted` as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/), the query would then be:

```
MATCH (n:Uid)-[r]->(n2)
WHERE n.uid IN $wanted AND n2 IN $wanted
RETURN r AS relation
```